# Installation of Miktex

Tags: latex

We have a Latex session tomorrow in our class, so our teacher sent a link to download it from https://miktex.org/download.

But I found it's something called MiKTeX and I'm using ubuntu 16, and I can see that there is no link to download it for ubuntu.

So what steps do I need to follow to match me with the students who will be using MikTeX in windows??
1.Install LaTex first??
2.Install Texlive
Then what else should I do??

Comment: According to the prerequisites you have to be running Windows to run miktex. You should inform your teacher of your difficulty (perhaps a windows machine can be made available to you) You could also try running the portable version under Wine or compiling it from the source available on the same page you linked.

Comment: I just tried compiling it, and I got stuck :|

Comment: I don't see the point of trying to run a Windows port of tex/latex in Linux - unless your class is *specifically* about features/usage of MiKTeX. I suggest you talk to your instructor about the exact course content and whether it is acceptable to use the native Ubuntu texlive/latex packages.

Comment: Use TeX Live in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

1)Since 2018 MikTeX offers also a version for Linux:
https://miktex.org/download

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list # Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list # Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install miktex
miktexsetup finish # for a private (for you only) TeX installation
# sudo miktexsetup --shared=yes finish # for a shared (system-wide) TeX installation
initexmf --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1 # if private (for enabling Autodownload)
# sudo initexmf --admin --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1 # if shared (for enabling Autodownload)
```

2) But on Linux I would recommend texlive:

> sudo apt-get install texlive

(there are several different commands, because some download just the minimal version `texlive-base` and if needed the texlive download more packages, others prefer initally to download the full verison `texlive-full`)

3) Theoretically you could use Wine (Windows for Linux), but I would not recommed it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415287/texniccenter-in-wine-on-linux